# import * as $ from "jQuery";

Tags: typescript-typings

I try to define jquery selector inside ts file but I have an error with message;

> [ts] Cannot find name '$'

here is the ss below;
[image]

I've searched on net somes taking about typings that I dont have in my project solution, if I need it to solve this can you also explain me how can I get in clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After

**npm install jquery --save**

and

**typings install dt~jquery --save**

you can use

**import * as $ from 'jquery';**

Then you should be able to work with

**$(...)**

In Aurelia you need to register the dependency "jquery", I don't know if something similar has to be done in Angular.

Answer (score 2):

The response is now rather

`npm install jquery @types/jquery`